# Hide element if that be outside of parent element

Tags: html, css, position

I want the section of this fish if its outside parent, be hidden.

This fish Css code is this

```
.fish {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This is jQuery mini project

[image: preview]

Comment: `This is jQuery mini project` -->where ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Who cares boss... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar to be sure your answer is correct `;)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah... Now I get it. But surely, it's a CSS fix na?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes but since jQuery is involved maybe there is more to do (overthinking maybe, but it's always good to see the code even if the solution is trivial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give `overflow: hidden; position: relative` to the parent:

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}
```

**Snippets:**

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccf;
  border: 5px solid #900;
}
.parent img {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=Fish" />
</div>
```

Check out without the given styles:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccf;
  border: 5px solid #900;
  position: relative;
}
.parent img {
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x50?text=Fish" />
</div>
```

**Preview**

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]